# C# SqlDataAdapter not populating DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have searched the net and searched the net only to not quite find the probably I am running into.  I am currently having an issue getting a SqlDataAdapter to populate a DataSet.  I am running Visual Studio 2008 and the query is being sent to a local instance of SqlServer 2008.  If I run the query SqlServer, it does return results.
Code is as follows:

```
string theQuery = "select Password from Employees where employee_ID = '@EmplID'";    
SqlDataAdapter theDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
theDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(theQuery, conn);
theDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EmplID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "EmployeeName";
theDataAdapter.Fill(theSet);
```

The code to read the dataset:

```
foreach (DataRow theRow in theSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //process row info
}
```

If there is any more info I can supply please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the query to say "select Password from Employees where employee_ID = @EmplID" (no single-quotes around the parameter).

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Second set of eyes is all it takes.  Sometimes they don't even have to be part of a smart head ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you run this query does it return results?

```
select Password from Employees where employee_ID = 'EmployeeName'
```

My guess is "EmployeeName" should be some passed in value....
and @EmpID shouldn't have single quotes around it in the query if you're using a parameter.